# Adding html form and input tags into Symfony static pages

Tags: symfony1

I inherited the management of a Symfony site and need to add some HTMl form tags to one of the "static" pages via the CMS. The scenario I have is:
/index.php/splash/welcome pulls up the welcome screen. 
We want to be able to add a subscription button on that page.
The HTML has been supplied for us by the company that handles the subscriptions. 
The form post method has an action that references a script on a remote site (no lectures on the security implications please ;-).
When I add the `<form... and <input`... tags via the CMS admin panel, the tags get removed automatically by Symfony.
Is there a way to tell Symfony to allow these tags?

Thanks in advance,
Marty.

Comment: Looks like your question has gotten clipped.

Answer (score 1):

This is goign to depend completely on how the developer set up the CMS. Youre using a rich text editor in source mode i would take a look at that editor's config file and documentation because its probably the one responsible for stripping the tags.

If its just a plain text area i would check the submit action for the edit form and take a look at the code... he may be using something to strip them in there.

If youre using one of the Symfony CMS plugins (Diem, Apostrophe, Sympal) i might be able to help further if i know which one youre using. If its something custom we would need to see the code. This isnt really indiciative of the Symfony core, but rather the CMS youre using.

Comment: OK - thanks for the tips, it got me moving in the right direction. The CMS uses tinymce as it's RT editor. Tinymce strips all potentially threatening html tags from any "textarea" box on submit. The only way I could find around this was to disable Javascript. Then the textarea text is rendered as straight text, not rich text, and saves without going through the tinymce js data validation. It's an ugly ugly fix, as it removes the WYSIWYG editing capabilities of the CMS - the content managers won't be too happy - I may have to change CMS's, unless someone knows a work around?

Comment: Update - symfony has a php file that initialises the tinymce editor. It has an extended_valid_elements tag, which I added the form and input tags to and voila, it works just fine! Here's the details: file is sfRichTextEditorTinyMCE.class.php, line I changed now looks like this: extended_valid_elements: "img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],form[name|action|target|method|style],input[type|name|size|value|style|class]", (last comma is deliberate). I hope this helps anyone who may run into the same issue!! Cheers,

Comment: You should be able to set that without modifying the actual class... there should be a method to configure it.